# Having an incedibly tough time with a loop

Tags: java, loops

I've copied part of the instructions below, and I can code pretty much every part on its own, but getting the control flow together is giving me massive doubts about my ability.

One of my biggest problems is the int gameChanger. Im supposed to immediately verify if it is a integer or not, and loop back if its not. But then Im also supposed to check to see if thebuser ever types "exit". But the input variable for my scanner instance is an integer... So Im stumped. I can use a try catch to check the missmatchexception once the input is being read in, but that doesnt solve the exit issue nor am I able to come up with solid logic to get the try catch to loop back if it indeed isnt an integer. Im thinking a do while loop but I havent gotten it to work.

Instructions:

Comment: tl;dr; - if you have to check for various types of input for a given loop then you either need to check that there's a value of the type *before* committing to the read or treat everything as a string and work it out afterwords. Take a look at the Scanner doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can whether the input is a number before attempting to consume it.

```
int num;
while (true) {
   if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
       num = scanner.nextInt();
       break;

   } else {
       // read whatever is there instead.
       String line = scanner.nextLine();
       if (line.equals("exit"))
            System.exit(0);
       System.out.println("Please enter a number");
   }
}

System.out.println("Number entered " + num);
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets the job done. Try it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyCode
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String gameInput = ".";
      int gameNumber = 0;
      boolean inputLoop = true;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      while(inputLoop == true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid game number: ");
            gameInput = input.next();

            if(gameInput.equals("exit"))
            {
               System.out.println("Program will now end. Goodbye.");
               inputLoop = false;
               input.close();
            }

            gameNumber = Integer.parseInt(gameInput);

            if(gameNumber >= 20001 && gameNumber <= 21230)
            {  
               System.out.println("You have inputted a valid game number.");
               inputLoop = false;
               input.close();
            }
         }
         catch(NumberFormatException e)
         {
            if(!gameInput.equals("exit"))
            {
               System.err.println("Invalid game number. Please try again.");
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```